# how can I distinguish between these curves

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry, plane-curves

the curve defined as 
$$f(x,y)=c$$
and $$f(x)=c$$
are plane or space curve 
i am confuse 
because $x^2 + y^2=4$ and $x^2=5 $
are both plane curves.But how can i decide about $f(x,y)=c$ and $f(x)=c$  whether they are plane or space curve.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, from the formula alone, tell whether there exist other letters that just happen to not appear. In the plane $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ gives a circle, while in space it gives an infinitely tall cylinder, and just from "$x^2 + y^2 = 1$" there is no way you can tell which one it is. You just have to take it from context.

Comment: what about $f(x)=c$

Comment: @NoorAslam It's similar: equation $f(x)=c$ has some set of solutions. Suppose it's finite, e.g. contains 3 numbers. Then in one-dimensional space the 'curve' is a 3-points subset of a real line; in 2D plane with cartesian system it's a set of three parallel lines (in a polar system it could be either 3 concentric circles or 3 rays); in 3D cartesian system it's 3 parallel planes, and so on...